# jQuery validator can't set error message for a field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
field: {

    required: true,
                messages: {
                required: 'this is a text for required'
                }
}
```

Why the messages property doesn't change the required message error?, is there a way to do that inside each field?

Comment: please share the complete validator code

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an error message for when a specific field does not pass a specific rule, but you do it like this:

```
{
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        field: {
            required: "error message when field is empty"
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In this case, "field" is the name of the input element.